# How to force inline math that would overflow, to break linebreak BEFORE the equation

Tags: math-mode, inline

I regularily encounter a situation where I have some piece of inline math that will overflow into the magin whenever it ends up on the right side of the page. Something like this: [image: example]

or [image: example 2]

I would like these equations to EITHER fit within the line they are on without overflowing (in that case leave them where they are) OR line break before the equation. I find myself doing this manually, adding a "//" before each equation when I see it sometimes overflowing, but this ends up being ugly when I change the layout later and it could have fit without a line break.

In short, I just want equations like this to be treated as "words" in a text. If the compiler can fit the word, it does, if it can't, it linebreaks. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: it does treat them exact;y like words and like a long unhyphnatable word it will overflow if white space can not stretch enough/ try replacing the equation with xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can `\-` be used in math mode to indicate where to break the formula?

Comment: In the first one I'd just allow it to line break `$z_1,z_2,\allowbreak z_3,z_4$\}`

Comment: @jlab no, \allowbreak, and it is only for inline math

Comment: Don't use `\-` in math it will work but having `-` appear is confusing, use `\*` as I just showed in my answer which is the same, but uses `\times` or use `\nolinebreak[1]` which allows but discourages a line break, and adds nothing at the breakpoint

Answer (score 2):

The math only has break points at relation sand binary operators, so it is like a large word with few hyphenation points, which will similarly overflow in some cases.

You can use `\sloppy` around the paragraph to allow white space to stretch more or place `\xlinebreak` defined as `\hfil\penalty-10\hfilneg`  which will do nothing if there is no linebreak but allow the line to be short if there is, or finally you could introduce more possible break points within the formula, here I use a discretionary `\times`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{-4cm}% just for the example
\newcommand\xlinebreak{\hfil\penalty-10\hfilneg}
\begin{document}

one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
$(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})
(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})
= 6$
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

\begin{sloppypar}

one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
$(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})
(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})
= 6$
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
\end{sloppypar}

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
\xlinebreak
$(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})
(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})(a_{i}b_{j})
= 6$
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
\xlinebreak
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
$(a_{i}b_{j})\*(a_{i}b_{j})\*(a_{i}b_{j})\*(a_{i}b_{j})\*
(a_{i}b_{j})\*(a_{i}b_{j})\*(a_{i}b_{j})\
= 6$
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
xx\-xx\-xx\-xx\-xx\-xx\-xx\-xx\-xx\-xx\-xx\-xx\-xx\-xx\-xx
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six
one two three four five six

\end{document}
```